# История кратких описаний метки?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, описание-метки

[метки](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В оригинале там "excerpt history". Почему у нас во множественном числе, а не просто "история краткого описания метки"?

Comment: Видимо кому-то когда-то показалось так правильным. Уже иначе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложенный перевод утверждён:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]